# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When using 2 or more words this search method works fine. But if there is only one word it gives the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens in.

`var_dump` of `$stmt` gives:

```
object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { 
    ["queryString"]=> string(117) "SELECT event_id, event_name FROM adrenaline_junkies_uk_events WHERE (`event_name` REGEXP ?) AND event_id <> ? LIMIT 3"
}
```

The bound variables appear to add up. What am I missing here?

heres the method:

```
public function getSimilarEvents($event_id, $nameArray) {
            $uniqueWords = array();
            // list of common words we dont want to search by
            $commonWords = array('a','able','you\'ve','z','zero');
            // Build array of words that dont match common words
            var_dump($uniqueWords = array_diff($nameArray, $commonWords));
            // Count how many words there are
            $wordCount = count($uniqueWords);
            // create where string to add to query
            $where_string = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0,$wordCount, "`event_name` REGEXP ?"));
            // build start of mysql query
            $query = "SELECT event_id, event_name FROM adrenaline_junkies_uk_events WHERE ($where_string) AND event_id <> ? LIMIT 3";
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
                    $x = 0;
            foreach($uniqueWords AS $index => $word){
                $stmt->bindValue($index+1, "[[:<:]]".$word."[[:>:]]", PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $x++;
            }
            $stmt->bindValue($x+1, $event_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            var_dump($stmt);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                return $stmt->fetchAll();
            }else{
                return $stmt->rowCount();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is my question not valid somehow?

Comment: You don't declare `$x` anywhere.

Comment: @Rocket okay I declare it now just before the `foreach()` loop but this doesn't appear to change anything.

Comment: What did you declare it to?  Try `bindValue($x` instead of `bindValue($x+1`.

Comment: surely it should be `$x+1`? which relates in this instance to the second `?` - the event_id I dont want it to return? (the event currently being viewed). The first bind is initiliased inside the `foreach()` loop `$index+1`. $index = 1 here, then it pops out of the loop and $x is assigned the value of 2 right? `$x+1`

Comment: @crm: Yes, I think you're right.  As long as you declared `$x = 0;`.

Comment: I've updated my code in the question to add `$x = 0` above the `foreach()` loop. This doesn't solve the warning I get

Comment: Just a thought, but [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) might be returning keys that aren't consecutive.  So, your `$index` might not be what you think it is.  Try `$uniqueWords = array_values(array_diff($nameArray, $commonWords));`

Comment: I appreciate your attempts: With your suggestion I get an array: `array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "event" }`. It didn't solve the warning I get. Its still the word word problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this line? You have to bind the `?` values here also:

```
$where_string = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0,$wordCount, "`event_name` REGEXP ?"));
```

AS said here, you don't bind the `?` in the `WHERE` creation. You have to bind those also. Move $x=0 up also!!

... Also, you don't provide it as parameter/binding, like you do with other variables (ok, is no user input here, but anyway).

Comment: This line is just fine.  [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) is a valid MySQL operator.  `$where_string` is being added to `$query`.  `$wordCount` is the length of `$uniqueWords`, which he is looping over.

Comment: This answer is a direct consequence of the bad question quality. Instead of poking in the dark in the answer, one have just to vote to close the question.

Comment: AS said here, you don't bind the `?` in the `WHERE` creation. You have to bind those also. Move $x=0 up also!!

Comment: Poking in the dark ... the line is and was incorrect. But you're right with closing posts ... I would delete 80% before anybody could even write a comment.

Comment: @djot I think you got it, will add another foreach to iterate through and append, right?

Comment: Yes, I got it, with eyes wide shut ... have other things to do than looking deeply into others problems ... go for the LOOP ! ... and still ... move `$x=0;` in front of that LOOP ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I must say Your Common Sense is not totally wrong ... so think about how to debug and read your code in the future. Also, reading, understanding(!) and googling error messages should be your daily job, if you want to call yourself a programer.

Answer (score 1):

To not rely on the value of `$index` (in foreach) you should better go with this:

```
 $x = 0;
 foreach($uniqueWords AS $index => $word){
   $x++;
   $stmt->bindValue($x, "[[:<:]]".$word."[[:>:]]", PDO::PARAM_STR);
 }
```

Also make sure, that you put an array here, even if it's only one value `$nameArray = array(7)`:

getSimilarEvents($event_id, $nameArray);

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the warning error I get.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff).

Let's say you have:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = array(1,4,3);
```

When you do `array_diff($a, $b);`, you get:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

And there's your problem.  When you do your `foreach`, your value of `$index` won't be what you'd expect it to be.

There are a few solutions here.  One is to use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to re-index the array:

```
$uniqueWords = array_values(array_diff($nameArray, $commonWords));
```

Another is to use your `$x` variable, instead of `$index` in `bindValue`:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($uniqueWords AS $word){
    $stmt->bindValue($x+1, "[[:<:]]".$word."[[:>:]]", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $x++;
}
$stmt->bindValue($x+1, $event_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rocket but I tried but of your siggestions and it doesn't solve the warning error.